# Saturn V set from the 60s?

Tags: set-identification, space

I have some of my dad's old Lego sets from the 1960s when he was a kid. There are circular discs that fit on top of each other to connect and form a rocket. Is this a Saturn V rocket model (the ones that took the Apollo astronauts to the moon) or perhaps some other rocket? What Lego sets like this were available in that period?

Comment: Welcome to LEGO Answers! If you have these pieces handy and could upload a photo, we could identify the set they come from more easily.

Comment: Yes, well, they are currently  in a bin with about a 1000 of my kids' other Legos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to answer this definitively without a picture identifying the exact parts you have, but this sounds a lot like the set Rocket Base (358-1) from 1973:

[image: 358]

That was one of the first space themed sets. The round parts are similar to what you've described. It looks like an obvious tribute to the Apollo program, though it isn't licensed or branded that way.

Comment: The rocket pieces look exactly like what I have, but I don't recall ever seeing those antenna pieces. Maybe they got broken before I came around though.

Comment: I could certainly imagine those antenna pieces breaking or going missing. Do you have the red baseplate that this is built on? Red baseplates are uncommon, and the one for this set also has a unique dot pattern: http://peeron.com/inv/parts/10p03

Comment: I'm not sure about the baseplate. I vaguely remember a broken piece we got rid of when I was a kid that might have been that. Or not. I'm going to have my dad take a look at this.

Comment: Those antennas are notorious for breaking, so I could easily imagine them being tossed sometime in the last 45 years, which might explain why you don't remember them.